# Getting an Index Out of Bounds Exception on my Android app - Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am creating an app from an android tutorial, everything looks fine before I add the images on my app
This is my code

```
MainActivity.kt

package com.example.memorygame

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.memorygame.models.BoardSize
import com.example.memorygame.utils.DEFAULT_ICONS

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var rvBoard: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var tvNumMoves: TextView
    private lateinit var tvNumPairs: TextView

    private var boardSize: BoardSize = BoardSize.HARD

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        rvBoard = findViewById(R.id.rvBoard)
        tvNumMoves = findViewById(R.id.tvNumMoves)
        tvNumPairs = findViewById(R.id.tvNumPairs)

        val chosenImages = DEFAULT_ICONS.shuffled().take(boardSize.getNumPairs())
        val randomizedImages = (chosenImages + chosenImages).shuffled()


        rvBoard.adapter = MemoryBoardAdapter(this, boardSize, randomizedImages)
        rvBoard.setHasFixedSize(true)

        rvBoard.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this, boardSize.getWidth())
    }
}
```

I have created another Kotlin class file which holds a ViewHolder and Binding of my images to the app. I have 3 modes which i want to add to this game which basically they are EASY, MEDIUM and HARD
The problem is that when i run my app on EASY and MEDIUM, I don't get any errors. Soon as I run it on HARD mode, which the array goes on 24, I get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

```
MemoryBoardAdapter.kt

package com.example.memorygame

import android.content.Context
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageButton
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.memorygame.models.BoardSize
import kotlin.math.min

class MemoryBoardAdapter(
    private val context: Context,
    private val boardSize: BoardSize,
    private val cardImages: List<Int>
) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<MemoryBoardAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    companion object{
        private const val MARGIN_SIZE = 10
        private const val TAG = "MemoryBoardAdapter"

    }


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val cardWidth = parent.width / boardSize.getWidth() - (2 * MARGIN_SIZE)
        val cardHeight = parent.height / boardSize.getHeight() - (2 * MARGIN_SIZE)
        val cardSideLength = min(cardWidth, cardHeight)
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.memory_card, parent, false)
        val layoutParams = view.findViewById<CardView>(R.id.cardView).layoutParams as ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams
        layoutParams.width = cardSideLength
        layoutParams.height = cardSideLength
        layoutParams.setMargins(MARGIN_SIZE, MARGIN_SIZE, MARGIN_SIZE, MARGIN_SIZE)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(position)
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = boardSize.numCards

    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        private val imageButton = itemView.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.imageButton)
        fun bind(position: Int){
            **imageButton.setImageResource(cardImages[position])**
            imageButton.setOnClickListener{
                Log.i(TAG, "Clicked on position $position")
            }
        }
    }

}


        **imageButton.setImageResource(cardImages[position])**
```

This line of code gets the images which I've saved on another kotlin class.
Everything is fine if I run my app on EASY and MEDIUM mode, but if I run my app on HARD mode for some reason my app just wont run and it says this message

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 20, Size: 20
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
        at com.example.memorygame.MemoryBoardAdapter$ViewHolder.bind(MemoryBoardAdapter.kt:51)
        at com.example.memorygame.MemoryBoardAdapter.onBindViewHolder(MemoryBoardAdapter.kt:43)
        at com.example.memorygame.MemoryBoardAdapter.onBindViewHolder(MemoryBoardAdapter.kt:15)
```

Here is my Declaration of my modes just in case, I don't think anything is wrong here

```
BoardSize.kt

package com.example.memorygame.models

enum class BoardSize(val numCards: Int) {
    EASY(8),
    MEDIUM(18),
    HARD(24);

    fun getWidth(): Int{
        return when (this){
            EASY -> 2
            MEDIUM -> 3
            HARD -> 4
        }
    }

    fun getHeight(): Int{
        return numCards / getWidth()
    }

    fun getNumPairs(): Int{
        return numCards / 2
    }
}
```

And btw, if i delete this line of code
imageButton.setImageResource(cardImages[position])
My app runs normal, without any new images that I registered,
but soon as I put this code on, my app starts to act weird
I know it may be hard to understand, but a little help would be so useful

Comment: what is the length of `cardImages` when it crashes? Surely you've run the code in a debugger or even just printed the value to the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that the root of the problem is right here:

```
val chosenImages = DEFAULT_ICONS.shuffled().take(boardSize.getNumPairs())
```

Based on the behavior that I see, `DEFAULT_ICONS` is probably limited at 10 items, which means that the maximum number of available items in `randomizedImages` will be 20 (way less than the 24 items needed for the adapter to work properly).

To fix this, you can change the implementation of the adapter to

```
override fun getItemCount() = cardImages.size
```

However, this will not provide the correct behavior for you app, but it should fix the crash. To make sure that everything works as expected, enforce the rule that `boardSize.numCards == cardImages.size`.

Comment: i haven't declared anything as size
The only size that i have is numCards which you can see it at my **BoardSize.kt**
I think everything from the code is good, i was guessing it's a device or a layout problem because im getting everything from a tutorial on youtube. It's so weird because it runs if i do not apply this code:
**imageButton.setImageResource(cardImages[position])**

It shows every image which i have on the app, not the new images i added though

Comment: What is the value of `DEFAULT_ICONS `?

Comment: I dont have a value, I just get the items from the drawable folder and i have declared as

val DEFAULT_ICONS = listOf(
R.drawable.ic_face,
etc.
etc.
)

Comment: `package com.example.memorygame.utils

import com.example.memorygame.R

// Creating a list of Images

val DEFAULT_ICONS = listOf(
    R.drawable.ic_face,
    R.drawable.ic_cloud,
    R.drawable.ic_flower,
    R.drawable.ic_gift,
    R.drawable.ic_hot,
    R.drawable.ic_restaurant,
    R.drawable.ic_tv,
    R.drawable.ic_volume,
    R.drawable.ic_wifi,
    R.drawable.ic_run
)`

Comment: Im sorry about my comments but this is like the beginning of me using stackOverflow, i hope u understand my point lol

Comment: Yes, I do. And I was right. Please read my answer again. Your list has only 10 items which will result in a list with 20 items after you shuffle it. But you need 24 items in the adapter to work properly. The rest of the cases (easy, medium) work because you need only 8 and 18 items. Also, the comment with DEFAULT_ICONS contains useful information, so it would be better to add it to the question.

Comment: So im looking at this as i need to add 2 more items on my DEFAULT_ICONS?
Thank you for your help btw, im a beginner on android development

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Add two more items and it should work.

Comment: You were right, i added 2 more items and my app is working right now.
Thank you for your help
***** five stars

Answer (score 0):

Trying to access index 20 while the size is just 20 means that there is a missing item on your list, check for your list size and replace 
`override fun getItemCount() = boardSize.numCards` to
`override fun getItemCount() = boardSize.size`
if the issue still persists try this `holder.absoluteAdapterPosition`.